# java - regex about duplicate words

Tags: java, regex

So, this regex means duplicate words: "\b(\w+)(\s+\1\b)+"

but what does the '+' do after the '\w'?
Wouldn't it  still identify duplicate words without the '+'?
Since the second parenthesis/group is the one identifying any repeats of the previous word.

Comment: `\w` matches 1 letter/digit/`_`. `\w+` matches **one or more** such chars.

Comment: omg thank you, \\w is actually a LETTER(or digit) not the full WORD

Comment: Yes, just Google about *quantifiers*.

Comment: Have a look at http://regexr.com/. They provide a nice overview about regex usage, and you can test your expressions pretty nicely.